# Hide Ultralytics' Yolov8 model.predict() output from terminal

Tags: python, output, stdout, yolo, yolov8

I have this output that was generated by `model.predict()`

```
0: 480x640 1 Hole, 234.1ms
Speed: 3.0ms preprocess, 234.1ms inference, 4.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)

0: 480x640 1 Hole, 193.6ms
Speed: 3.0ms preprocess, 193.6ms inference, 3.5ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)

...
```

How do I hide the output from terminal?

I can't find out the information in this official link
https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#arguments

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Ultralytics docs are sadly not up to date, as of today. The right way of doing this is:

```py
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8m-seg.pt')
results = model.predict(source='0', verbose=False)
for result in results:
    masks = result.masks.masks
    print(masks.shape)
```

Notice the `verbose=False` argument. This won't print the default output

```bash
...
0: 480x640 1 Hole, 193.6ms
Speed: 3.0ms preprocess, 193.6ms inference, 3.5ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
...
```

In this case only:

```bash
...
torch.Size([4, 480, 640])
...
```

Comment: Are there any sources for this and other extra arguments

Comment: https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#inference-arguments

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to redirect the standered output to **dev/null** *(wich actually discards all outputs and you will not even see errors)* with the help of **os** module and **contextlib** module as follow:

```
import os
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
  with redirect_stdout(devnull):
    result = modle.predict
```